# Simple WSDL, getting a ConnectException

Tags: eclipse, wsdl, soa

i really need help with the simpliest things of WSDL.

i got the following WSDL, which is basically just generated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="MyFirstWSDL"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/MyFirstWSDL/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/MyFirstWSDL/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/MyFirstWSDL/">
        <xsd:element name="getName">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="in" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="getNameResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="out" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="getNameRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getName"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="getNameResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getNameResponse"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="MyFirstInterface">
    <wsdl:operation name="getName">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getNameRequest"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getNameResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="NewBinding" type="tns:MyFirstInterface">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getName">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://www.example.org/MyFirstWSDL/getName" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="MyFirstService">
    <wsdl:port name="MyFirstPort" binding="tns:NewBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8197/MyFirstService/" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Now, when generating a provider and testing the service with the "Web Services Explorer" I keep getting the following exception:

```
IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred.
java.net.ConnectException
Connection refused: connect
```

So, do you have any clue or suggestions to solve this problem?

thx in advance, matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because http://localhost:8197/MyFirstService/ is not answering from where you call it.

You can try to check this by telnetting there or simply putting the Address in a browser window.

Though as it is localhost, you should know if you started the server, that is accepting the web service client or not.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when putting it into the browser window. But that should be fine, because the Web Service Explorer is doing some magic here ;) I tried it with a given WSDL with the same setup and it works, just my self written version doesn't

Comment: I got the same problem Could u detail solution?